# Using Ruby .map Method To Combine Arrays With Unique Nested Values

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the map function to combine an array of arrays into an array of arrays that eliminate a unique value in arr[0][0] but pull arr[0][1] and group it with the corresponding unique value.

```
arr = [[a, 1], [a, 2], [b,3], [b, 4]]
=> [[a, [1, 2]], [b, [3,4]]]
```

I'm sure this is pretty basic but I'm rather new to coding in general. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start with `group_by`, _then_ you'll need `map`

Comment: Whenever you give an example please show the desired or expected result as a Ruby object. We must assume that `a` and`b` are unstated variables or methods. If they are intended to be strings or symbols write`"a"` or `:a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:b, 3], [:b, 4]]

arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }
#=> [[:a, [1, 2]], [:b, [3, 4]]]
```

Depending on what your goal is, you might want to turn the result into a hash:

```
Hash[arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)] }]
#=> {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 4]}
```